# How to call javascript function on day SelectionChanged event of calender control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White"
        BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender"
        OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged"
        Height="190px" Style="margin-left: 168px;" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" 
        Width="423px">
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
        <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399"
            BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" />
    </asp:Calendar>
```

I have one calender control as above and I want to display one popup message through javascript function when we click on any of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply as :

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#Calendar1 tbody tr td', function(event){
alert("my message...");
//... other code if needed
});
```